# Detect key press when there is a collision/trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object and I'm trying to get the player to enter the trigger and press a key, swap the camera.

My code:

```
public class Canhao : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cameraPlayer;
    public Camera CameraCanhao;


    private void Start()
    {
        cameraPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        CameraCanhao.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            if(cameraPlayer.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                cameraPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                CameraCanhao.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

    }
```

But he is not respecting the condition of pressing the C key, and simply switching the camera when the player enters the trigger. Im forgetting something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check input in a physics callback function. Set a flag to `true` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function then to `false` in the `OnTriggerExit` function. You can then check the flag in the `Update` function. The `Update` function is also where you should check if the 'C' key is pressed since that's checked every frame.

Finally, to check if there is a trigger while 'C' key is pressed, use `&&` not `||`. When you use `||`, it means that the `if` statement will validate to `true` when any of the condition is `true` but you want both to be `true` so `&&` should be used.

```
public Camera cameraPlayer;
public Camera CameraCanhao;
bool triggered = false;

private void Start()
{
    cameraPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    CameraCanhao.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && triggered)
    {
        if (cameraPlayer.gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            cameraPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            CameraCanhao.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        triggered = true;
    }

}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        triggered = false;
    }
}
```

Note that if this is not working for you, make sure to put `Debug.Log` inside `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` verify that they are being called. If they are not being called then make sure that "Is Trigger" is enabled on the colliders and that a `Rigidbody` is attached to the colliders too.

Comment: worked in parts, the TriggerExit function does not work

Comment: Don't worry about `OnTriggerExit`. It will be called when the object is no longer touching the player. You're fine as long as `OnTriggerEnter` is working fine

Answer (score 2):

You are puting TRIGGER || KEYPRESS you must replace the || with &&.

```
if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
```